# Are there studies about the use of categories and tags?

Tags: blog

I recently had a [discussion about tag- and category pages in blogs](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1919#issuecomment-31778738) and I'm currently thinking about dropping categories completely.

Are there any studies that analyze if/how users use categories and tags, especially when they are combined?

Comment: This answer to a question about the difference between tags and categories is relevent here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/34816/32025

Answer (score 4):

I've read a lot on this in the past and, across numerous websites have tinkered between categories vs tags somewhat. I haven't really seen a study as such that drills down into the UX and visitor behaviour surrounding categories and tags but [this piece](http://avalaunchmedia.com/blog/categories-vs-tags-usage-organization-seo) is pretty good on the subject.

There is a great amount of web content on the subject, some of which is pretty uselss but here's various takes on the subject worth a read:-

- http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Categories_vs_Tags.aspx/
- http://www.usabilitypost.com/2008/10/17/categories-vs-tags/
- http://www.seosherpas.com/wordpress-tags-or-categories/
- http://www.dailybloggr.com/2008/04/tags-and-categories-seo-and-usability/

And, [here is what Matt Cutts from Google says on the subject](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A96yDPqa2rs).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I also spent quite some time reading my self in to the usage of tags and categories. Every source so far (including your links unfortunately) either describes the SEO purpose and/or describes, how tags/categories differ and how to use them when editing. Both have nothing to do with usability. None describe how the end-user benefits from them. Especially concerning tags.

Comment: I'm actually the owner of SEOSherpas and the author of the article that Geoff posted. My entire article focuses specifically on the end-user benefits (or lack thereof) of them. Yes, we go into detail about the SEO factors, but most of the article focuses on the end-user benefits. At the end, there's even a little snippet about how to implement them on your site in an SEO and end-user friendly way using some custom PHP. Hope that helps!